# How to authorize with AJAX from PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, authorization, guzzle

How can I authorize with PHP (with Guzzle) at https://my.tiu.ru/cabinet/sign-in ?
I've inspected - it uses AJAX to commit the authorize form.

I've tried to use some JS-scripts to login from browser console (both scripts work):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://my.tiu.ru/cabinet/sign-in',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { phone_email: 'ifnnfadl@emltmp.com', password: 'MKO09ijn', email: 'ifnnfadl@emltmp.com'},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://my.tiu.ru/cabinet/auth/phone_login',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { phone_email: 'ifnnfadl@emltmp.com', password: 'MKO09ijn'},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

But a simple PHP-script does not:

```
try {
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://my.tiu.ru',
        'verify'    => false,
        'cookies'  => true,
        'headers'  => [
            'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
        ]
    ]);

    $auth_page = $client->request('GET', '/cabinet/sign-in');
    // var_dump($auth_page->getBody()->getContents());

    // $login = $client->request('POST', '/cabinet/auth/phone_login', [
    //  'form_params' => [
    //      'phone_email' => 'ifnnfadl@emltmp.com',
    //      'email'       => 'ifnnfadl@emltmp.com',
    //      'password'    => 'MKO09ijn'
    //  ]
    // ]);
    // var_dump($login->getBody()->getContents());

    $login = $client->request('POST', '/cabinet/sign-in', [
        'form_params' => [
            'phone_email' => 'ifnnfadl@emltmp.com',
            'email'       => 'ifnnfadl@emltmp.com',
            'password'    => 'MKO09ijn'
        ]
    ]);
    var_dump($login->getBody()->getContents());
}
catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException$e) {
    echo GuzzleHttp\Psr7\str($e->getRequest());
    if ($e->hasResponse()) {
        echo GuzzleHttp\Psr7\str($e->getResponse());
    }
}
```

It returns only 403 error

P.S. login and password are temp, feel free to use them

Comment: why is the login inside an array "form_params"?

Comment: hm? these params are required for login

Comment: yes, but why are they inside an array? `'form_params' => [1,2,3]` is not the same as `[1,2,3]` as you would have to look inside `'form_params'` to get the values

Comment: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#form-params

Comment: i am not to deep in that whole ssl thing but if your address protocol is `https:` dont you have to use the `'verify'    => true,`